# How to get compatible with php4 in a framework developed with php5

Tags: php, php4

How to get compatible with php4 in a framework developed with php5?

Thanks

Comment: Considering PHP 4 is not supported anymore (not even for security-related problems !), I would drop support for that old version, require PHP >= 5.2, and benefit from the "new" features and functionnalities, that will really make your life easier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not too late you could use a framework like [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) or [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) that support both.  Otherwise, it sounds like a losing battle that is not worth the effort.

If you are developing something from scratch, I agree with the other answers PHP5 is the only way to go.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like an unnecessary waste of time.

I'd suggest using PHP5 instead.

As you are asking about a framework i assume that it is object oriented, and as such is not what i consider a candidate for backporting to PHP4.

To make me even consider the process of doing so you would have to convince me that there is in fact a solid reason for doing so. I cannot see there is one at this point.

Backporting for the sake of running a single instance of the framework is nothing but stupid. If this is due to some webhosting company that does not yet offer PHP5, just switch to another better hosting provider.

Comment: consider codeigniter, it is also oop but supports php4 too. any way i agree to dis-consider php4 now i suppose.

Comment: yeah, you basically have two options, use another framework that supports both or run it on php5 if you're stuck with the framework. if it's a really small framework developed by yourself, then maybe you could do it.